# How to open div as a tooltip in Grid in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<style>
    #hint{
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .tooltip{
        margin:8px;
        padding:8px;
        border:1px solid white;
        background-color:#e2e2e2;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        display:none;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
<a href="#" rel="@item.Email" class="anchorlink">@Html.Raw(item.FirstName + " " + item.MiddleName + " " + item.LastName)</a>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.anchorlink').mouseover(function (e) {
            var id = $(this).attr("rel");
            $('.tooltip').show().html(id);
        }).mousemove(function (e) {
            $('.tooltip').css('left', (e.pageX - 20) + 'px');
            $('.tooltip').css('top', (e.pageY + 20) + 'px');
        }).mouseout(function (e) {
            $('.tooltip').hide().html('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: show live html, not server code when problem is client side. There is no element `class=tooltip` shown in the html in question. You also really need to read up on how to ask questions here

Comment: You can learn html here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: How to open a **div** as tooltip. Where is that **div**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the actual tooltip element in your html:

```
 <div class="tooltip"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing you `<div class="tooltip"></div>` inside your html body.